# spring-ws : Wss4jSecurityInterceptor UserNameToken along with Signature securementActions

Tags: java, spring-ws, wss4j

Using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to add *userNameToken and Signature* securementActions does not work because BinarySecurityToken and UsernameToken takes the same password and userName from securityInterceptor

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    CryptoFactoryBean crypto = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    crypto.setKeyStoreLocation(getResourceFrom(keyStoreLocation));
    crypto.setKeyStorePassword(encryptorService.decrypt(keyStorePassword));
    crypto.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
    crypto.afterPropertiesSet();

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(crypto.getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(userName);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(encryptorService.decrypt(password));

    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

if the userName and password are the same for both, then it works, how can I set different userName password.

it was possible before using : securementCallbackHandlers, but with version wpring-ws 2.4.2 that is not possible anymore

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution after debuging the inner of springboot:

created a **CustomUserNameTokenAction**:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class CustomUserNameTokenAction implements Action {

        private String userName;
        private String password = "";

        public void execute(WSHandler handler, SecurityActionToken actionToken,
                            Document doc, RequestData reqData)
                throws WSSecurityException {
            String username = userName; 
            WSSecUsernameToken builder = new WSSecUsernameToken();
            builder.setIdAllocator(reqData.getWssConfig().getIdAllocator());
            builder.setPrecisionInMilliSeconds(reqData.isPrecisionInMilliSeconds());
            builder.setWsTimeSource(reqData.getWssConfig().getCurrentTime());
            builder.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
            builder.setPasswordsAreEncoded(reqData.isEncodePasswords());
            builder.setUserInfo(username, password);
            builder.build(doc, reqData.getSecHeader());
        }
    }
```

I also created a class to wrap config of the username and password

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class UserNameTokenConfig {
        private String userName;
        private String password;
    }
```

My code for the security interceptor becomes:

```
    @Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

        CryptoFactoryBean crypto = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        crypto.setKeyStoreLocation(getResourceFrom(keyStoreLocation));
        crypto.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
        crypto.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
        crypto.afterPropertiesSet();

        securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(crypto.getObject());
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(keyAlias);
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(keyPassword);

        val wssConfig = WSSConfig.getNewInstance();
        wssConfig.setAction(1, new CustomUserNameTokenAction(userNameToken.getUserName(), userNameToken.getPassword()));
        securityInterceptor.setWssConfig(wssConfig);

        return securityInterceptor;
    }
```

so

```
       securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(keyAlias);
       securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(keyPassword);
```

are used for the **WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE**

and

```
     val wssConfig = WSSConfig.getNewInstance();
        wssConfig.setAction(1, new CustomUserNameTokenAction(userNameToken.getUserName(), userNameToken.getPassword()));
        securityInterceptor.setWssConfig(wssConfig);
```

is used for the **WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN**

hope this will help